# Comparing different string-matching functions

Tags: python, performance, strings, memory-management, comparative-review

Here is a problem came from [codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p182414):

> Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where
>   they contain the same length 2 substring. So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz"
>   yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az"  substrings appear in the
>   same place in both strings.

There are several answers but it may hard to choose which one is the most preferred, such as:

```
# Solution 1
# Using for loop
def strmatch_forloop(a, b):
    shorter = min(len(a), len(b))
    count = 0
    for i in range(shorter-1):
        a_sub = a[i:i+2]
        b_sub = b[i:i+2]
        if a_sub == b_sub:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

```
# Solution 2
# Using list comprehension
def strmatch_listcomp(a, b):
    shorter = min(len(a), len(b))
    return [a[i:i+2] == b[i:i+2] for i in range(shorter-1)].count(True)
```

```
# Solution 3
# Using generator
def strmatch_gen(a, b):
    shorter = min(len(a), len(b))
    return sum(a[i:i+2] == b[i:i+2] for i in range(shorter-1))
```

Note that the "preferable" might be subjective; it may refer to the speed, the memory use or the coding style. For instance, their speeds are reported as:

> ```
> %timeit strmatch_forloop
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ns per loop
>
> %timeit strmatch_listcomp
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 22.9 ns per loop
>
> %timeit strmatch_gen
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 ns per loop
> ```

According to the results, there may no difference between these approaches. For memory use, similar results can be shown by `%memit`. However, coding style is too subjective to measure. How could I choose among them?

Comment: In general (depending on how efficient this has to be) I would choose whichever one looks the most natural to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since memory and performance metrics are similar, coding style is possibly the only differentiating factor.

Nothing wrong with solution 1 but it takes more time to read it, unless you are paid by the number of lines you write! I guess it is Pythonic to write code in fewer lines so long as readability is not compromised.

I prefer solution 3. It reads well and terse. Solution 2 is just as good but it appears to be doing extra work in the sense of creating a list and then counting. Why do that when you can directly sum up the matches?